# Check a platform isn't already in place before instantiating a new one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm using the following code to instanciate a platform for the 3d platform game i'm making:

```
Instantiate(platforms[Random.Range(1, platforms.GetLength(0))], position, Quaternion.identity);
```

The game object that this script is attatched to is constantly moving to the right, however, how can I avoid platforms being placed on top of each other? I tried getting the size of the collider but couldn't get it to work. I think I need an if statement that checks if a platform is already in place before instantiating in that position (but i'm a a beginner so i'm not sure how to start).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any method that can tell you if a GameObject was or not Instantiated in a certain place. 
The collider's size gives you the local size of the collider, where the collider's bounds gives you the global.

collider.bounds.size.x - will give you the size of your object on x. To verify if your new object will overlap the existing one on x just write:

```
(oldObject.transom.position.x + oldObjectCollider.bounds.size.x  > newObject.transform.position.x) || (oldObject.transom.position.x - oldObjectCollider.bounds.size.x < newObject.transform.position)
```